# Estimates of the global STEM workforce?

Tags: reference-request, data-request, labor-economics

I am looking for any recent estimates of the global STEM workforce (STEM = Science Technology Engineering Mathematics, and ideally includes software engineers).

Time series data would be even better, but I understand how unlikely it is to find such data.

Comment: [opendata.se] might be a good place to ask, as you're not asking about economics concepts, but rather about locating a dataset

Comment: @EnergyNumbers - thanks for the tip, I posted my question there as well.